# Using react cloneElement to over-ride prop type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this `TextField` component, which is input form that takes in string and using React.cloneElement, I'm trying to create `NumberField`, which is another input form, but takes in number type. There are two props `value` and `onChange` from `TextField` that I would like to change from string to number as I use React.cloneElement to copy over, but I'm getting type errors on `e.currentTarget.value` from `NumberField` saying "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'." I also get another error in App.js on `e.target.value` saying "Property 'target' does not exist on type 'number'." All I'm trying to do is use cloneElement to over-ride prop types from string to number, but it's proving difficult. What am I doing wrong? https://codesandbox.io/s/over-ride-prop-type-mjw1sp?file=/src/App.tsx

TextField.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export interface ITextField {
  onChange?: (value: string) => void;
  value?: string;
}

export const TextField: React.FC<ITextField> = ({ value = "", onChange }) => {
  const onChangeValue = (value: string) => {
    if (typeof onChange === "function") {
      onChange(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
          onChangeValue(e.currentTarget.value)
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

NumberField.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { TextField, ITextField } from "./TextField";

export interface INumberField extends Omit<ITextField, "onChange" | "value"> {
  onChange?: (value: number) => void;
  value: number;
  formatOnType?: boolean;
}

export const NumberField: React.FC<INumberField> = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  const [numberValue, setNumberValue] = useState<number>(0);
  const onChangeValue = (value: number) => {
    if (typeof onChange === "function") {
      onChange(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {React.cloneElement(<TextField />, {
        value: numberValue,
        onChange: (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
          onChangeValue(e.currentTarget.value)
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NumberField } from "./NumberField";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <NumberField value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what props means and how to assign them.
This is just a copy paste of same code everywhere

        onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
          onChangeValue(e.currentTarget.value)
        }

Comment: can you clearly explain what you are trying to achieve?
Why do you need to copy the TextField component if you can use it instead of new NumberField? That doesn't make sense

Comment: Also in you TextField component you should pass function as a prop, that is why you are getting errors

Comment: Log out typeof e.target.value, it will be string.
Whereas in your number component you set the type as a number

Comment: Trying to use cloneElement to over-ride props types of TextField from string to number. I'm experimenting with cloneElement.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML inputs (and in react inputs), for values are strings.`React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>` always return a string. Now I understand you want to store a number. With a standalone component, that would give the following:

```
export interface INumberField extends Omit<ITextField, "onChange" | "value"> {
  onChange?: (value: number) => void;
  value: number;
  formatOnType?: boolean;
}

export const NumberField = ({ value, onChange }: INumberField) => {
  // the input typed by the user is always a string
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('0');

  const handleChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const numberValue = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
      onChange(numberValue)
      setValue(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        {/* automatically converted to string */}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
   );
};
```

As for reusing a TextField to build a NumberField, I'm afraid you'll be fighting (and losing) against TypeScript. The right way to do it would be to write a generic input, and to specialize it by type.

```
export interface IField<T> {
  onChange: (value: T) => void;
  value: T;
  convert?: (value: string) => T;
}

export const Field = <T>({ value, onChange, convert = x => x }: IField<T>) => {{
  // the input typed by the user is always a string
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('0');

  const handleChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const parsedValue = convert(e.target.value);
      onChange(parsedValue)
      setNumberValue(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        {/* automatically converted to string */}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
   );
};
```

Then your fields are:

```
export interface ITextField extends IField<string> {}
const TextField = (props: ITextField) => <Field<string> {...props} /> 

export interface INumberField extends IField<number> {}
const NumberField = ({ value, onChange }: INumberField) => (
    <Field<number> value={value} onChange={onChange} convert={v => parseInt(v, 10)} /> 
);
```

Comment: I guess I picked wrong component to practice cloneElement. Just wanted to over-ride props from already built-in component, but it seems more complicated than I expected. In this example, is this called Component composition? Where you build general base of the component(Field component in this case) then NumberField or TextField build on top of it to their specificity?

Comment: Yes, this is component composition!